# Identity scaffold pages not found at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I scaffold my identity pages so that their appeared in areas/account

[image]

/Account/Login

But now when I go to the Account/Login its not found should it not have created a Account controller for me as well ?

My Start-up is told to use identity so don't get it.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(
         Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));          
         services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
         options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();          
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use area name in URL

```
/Identity/Account/Login
```

> should it not have created a Account controller for me as well?

no, because it use [Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Yes that worked thanks when should one use pages versus controllers? Say If I am doing a e-comemrce site should I use pages for the check out etc.

Comment: It's up to you. Commonly,  pages used for SPA applications. If you like to work with "feature" approach and "vertical slices design" then try pages. You can mix controllers and pages in the same app. Read more about pages and check if it fits to you